# Copy data from textfile to Excel

Tags: vbscript

Here is the code to copy the data from a textfile and paste it to Excel. I have split the text by `vbNewline`, but I also need to split it by space.

Is there any alternative method to split the data by space, and how to split the data by both `vbNewLine` *and* space?

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objFSO, strTextFile, strData, strLine, arrLines

Const ForReading = 1

path = InputBox("Enter the path :","Select Your Path !","Type your path here")

'name of the text file
strTextFile = path

'Create a File System Object
Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open the text file - strData now contains the whole file
strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile, ForReading).ReadAll

'typesplit=inputbox("Enter the type ","Type to split(VbnewLine (or) <Space>)","vbnewline/space")

'Split the text file into lines
arrLines = Split(strData, vbNewLine)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

intRow = 2
k = 0

align = InputBox("Enter the type of alignment...(default/horizontal/vertical)", _
        "Press h (or) v (or) d")

If (align = "v") Then
  rowlimit = InputBox("Enter the row limit")
  For i=1 To 10 Step 1
    For j=1 To rowlimit Step 1
      objExcel.Cells(j, i).Value = arrLines(k)
      k = k+1
    Next
  Next
End If

If (align = "h") Then
  collimit = InputBox("Enter the col limit")
  For i=1 To 10 Step 1
    For j=1 To collimit Step 1
      objExcel.Cells(i, j).Value = arrLines(k)
      k = k+1
    Next
  Next
End If

MsgBox("Conversion Finished !!")

Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Why should the user have to enter things like row limit and col limit? Couldn't it be inferred from the data? You could consider replacing spaces by commas in the text file and saving it as a csv file -- which Excel knows how to open (and run a transpose for the other alignment). Also, look into how text-to-columns works in Excel.

Comment: You could also try automating the [Text to Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) functionality

Comment: Yes, i will try thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript doesn't allow you to split a string by multiple delimiters in one step. You need to split it by the first delimiter, then loop over the resulting array and split the substrings by the second delimiter, and so on.

```
For Each line In Split(strData, vbNewLine)
  For Each word In Split(line, " ")
    'do something with each word
  Next
Next
```

If you want to put all words into a single array for later processing you'd put them into a dynamically resizable array:

```
ReDim words(-1)  'define empty resizable array
For Each line In Split(strData, vbNewLine)
  For Each word In Split(line, " ")
    ReDim Preserve words(UBound(words)+1)
    words(UBound(words) = word
  Next
Next
```

Alternatively you could use an [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Set words = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each line In Split(strData, vbNewLine)
  For Each word In Split(line, " ")
    words.Add word
  Next
Next
```

Beware that dynamic VBScript arrays perform poorly with large amounts of data, because every time you resize the array the interpreter creates a new array, copies all data from the existing array, then assigns the new array to the variable.

On the other hand, instantiating an `ArrayList` object means a lot of overhead, so it doesn't perform as well as VBScript builtin arrays for small amounts of data.

Comment: @sebastinsaba You're welcome. John Coleman raises some valid points, though. Your question isn't too clear about what you need the "manual" row/column limits for. There may be better ways to handle your data, depending on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: If i use for each loop instead of for loop, will the corresponding values to the cells can insert properly like (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3) vice versa.

Comment: You'd need additional counter variables, but in principle that's possible. It depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your response